# Injector file in Apache-Nutch-1.12

Tags: apache, cygwin, nutch

**$./crawl seeds firsttry localhost:8080**

I am running this command and getting the below shown error.

**/home/apache-nutch-1.12/bin/nutch inject firsttry/crawldb seeds
   Failed with exit value 127.**

The injector file is not been created in the nutch folder..

I am confused if I have to create this manually or it will be created automatically..

Please help....

Comment: The folder (or file) seeds must exist in the current directory, firsttry/crawldb is created automatically. The hadoop.log (in folder logs) should contain more details what went wrong.